# Access is denied Exception when updating List items using SPUserToken

Tags: sharepoint

I try to do some actions on Sharepoint 2010 list using an unlowed user( having only read right) and i got Access denied exception. 
Is it possible to do it whithout changing the user rights.
please find below my code:

```
public void StartWorkFlow(int itemID, int wfTemplateID, String entityName, String userShortname)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPUser spUser;
            using (site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    spUser = web.EnsureUser(userShortname);
                }
            }
            using (site = new SPSite(siteUrl, spUser.UserToken))
            {
                using (web = site.AllWebs["WPrs"])
                {
                    list = web.Lists["Workflow Template"];
                    SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(wfTemplateID);
                    SPList processList = web.Lists["List Process " + item["Template_x0020_Name"]];
                    SPListItem newInstance = processList.Items.Add();
                    newInstance["Template_x0020_Name"] = item["Template_x0020_Name"];
                    newInstance["Template_x0020_Description"] = item["Template_x0020_Description"];
                    newInstance["Date_x0020_De_x0020_Publication"] = item["Date_x0020_De_x0020_Publication"];
                    newInstance["Item_x0020_Id"] = itemID;
                    newInstance["Item_x0020_Extradata"] = entityName.ToLower() + "||Parameter||" + "";
                    newInstance["CTName"] = Utility.GetInstance().GetSuperItemNameBySubItemName(entityName);
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    newInstance.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use site.AllWebs the user must have Full Control to the site. Instead of using AllWebs try to get the sub sites using the following code -

SPWebCollection subwebs = CurrentSite.OpenWeb().GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getsubwebsforcurrentuser%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e7ff284f-fe4b-42fb-8b21-a475e331a18c/access-denied-for-user-with-contribute-rights?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Also you would not be able to update a listitem with read only rights.

Comment: There is no way to do it? Because in the list tasks i need to insert the user passed as a parameter(the action initiator) in the column 'Created By'(InternalName: Author).

Comment: but why you need to create SPsite and spweb objects with SPusertoken? You can update the items under SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        only.

Comment: In my case, I have a web application Asp.Net MVC 4 that calls WCF services. In the WCF services application pool identity, I'm using Administrator identity. So to distinguish wich user do the action, I passed his login as a parameter to the called service, and I need to use the SPUserToken to can be inserted in the SPList columns( Created By, Modified By).

Answer (score 0):

If the only requirement is to set up the Created By/Modified By field - you should be able to overwrite default value by using SystemUpdate instead of Update. But still you need to run this  `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` mode instead of `UserToken`

Although I'm not sure what will happen if have any other dependent actions after this update (event receivers or workflows) i'm not sure what context it will use (i.e. if SharePoint internally will use current `SPWeb.CurrentUser` object.